# Mandist predicate not giving expected results

Tags: prolog, sliding-tile-puzzle

So I'm trying to find the direction that the blank tile in the 8 tile puzzle will be sliding,

I am using X/Y to determine the tiles.

Here's the code I have.

```
mandist( X /Y , X1 / Y1 , D, Direction):-
       D is abs(X - X1 )+ abs(Y - Y1 ),
       Y is Y1  ->(
           (   X is X1 +1 -> Direction ='left')
           ;
           (   X1 is X +1 -> Direction = 'right'))
       ;  X is X1 ->(
               (   Y1 is Y +1 -> Direction ='up')
           ;
           (   Y is Y1 +1 -> Direction ='down')).
```

The problem I'm getting is that when calling the mandist predicate it isn't giving me the results I had hoped for.

I am sure the problem is with the if statement, I have wrote some psuedocode so you can understand what I'm  trying to do,

```
if(Y == Y1){
    // Change the X Axis
    if(X == X1 +1){
        This is a left move
    }
    else{
        This is a right move
    }
}else if (X == X1){
    // Change the Y Axis 
    if(Y == Y1 + 1){
        This is an up move
    }
    else{
        This is a down move
    }
}
```

Example:

```
move([1/1, 3/1, 1/3, 2/3, 3/3, 1/2, 2/2, 3/2,2,1], X, Direction)
```

This then calls the mandist predicate

With D set to 1, so it ensures its a legal move

Here is the unexpected result:

```
mandist(1/1, X,1, Direction).
Direction = up ;
false
```

I am also expecting it to say `Direction = right` because position 1/1 is the very bottom left of the 3x3 grid and the only moves from the bottom left are either up or right

`1/3 2/3 3/3`

`1/2 2/2 3/2`

`1/1 2/1 3/1`

Comment: What is the final `else` case?

Comment: There is no final else @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: so in that case the predicate should fail? What should happen if `Y` is not equal to `Y1` nor `X` is equal to `X1`?

Comment: Then its an illegal move so it should fail

Comment: You wrote " it isn't giving me the results I had hoped for" but... can you give us an example of unexpected result? What do you expect and what do you obtain?

Comment: Sure, check my edit @max66

Comment: @user3667111: in your example you use `move` instead of `mandist`. Is this a typo? Furthermore all of a sudden, the distance has disappeared.

Comment: Sorry I updated it @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: I'm also getting ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, you probably want to write the following clause:

```
mandist(X/Y,XD/Y,D,right) :-
    XD is X+D.
mandist(X/Y,X/YD,D,up) :-
    YD is Y+D.
mandist(X/Y,XD/Y,D,left) :-
    XD is X-D.
mandist(X/Y,X/YD,D,down) :-
    YD is Y-D.
```

Given you write this to the file, it will generate:

```
?- mandist(1/1,X,1,Direction).
X = 2/1,
Direction = right ;
X = 1/2,
Direction = up ;
X = 0/1,
Direction = left ;
X = 1/0,
Direction = down.
```

Furthermore it can validate whether two coordinates are located in a certain direction **given `D` us instantiated**:

```
?- mandist(1/1,1/2,1,Direction).
Direction = up ;
false.
```

However it will not work with:

```
?- mandist(1/1,1/2,D,Direction).
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

There is however a way to do this. Please updated your question if that is a requirement.

**EDIT:**

Since there are bounds, you can simply add them to the clauses. **If you can assume that the first pair of coordinates are valid**, it is simply:

```
mandist(X/Y,XD/Y,D,right) :-
    XD is X+D,
    XD < 4.
mandist(X/Y,X/YD,D,up) :-
    YD is Y+D,
    YD < 4.
mandist(X/Y,XD/Y,D,left) :-
    XD is X-D,
    XD > 0.
mandist(X/Y,X/YD,D,down) :-
    YD is Y-D,
    YD > 0.
```

Comment: But say 1/1 is at the bottom left of the tile, then we shouldn't be able to move down or left

Comment: `1/3 2/3 3/3`  
`1/2 2/2 3/2`
`1/1 2/1 3/1`

Comment: Ah so there are bounds. Those bounds are simply *greater than or equal to one*? Or are there upper bounds as well?

Comment: Well it has to be within the confines of the 3/3 grid, so no greater than 3/3 and no less than 1/1

Comment: @user3667111: see updated answer. Does this resolve the problem?